# Scala type erasure in pattern matching Map[String, Any]

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I am using scala version 2.12.3, and when I test some pattern match in console code:

```
val d: Any = Map("1" -> "2", "3" -> 4)
d match {
    case map: Map[String, Any] => println(map)
    case _ => println("should not be here")
}
```

I got some warning like `<console>:14: warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] (the underlying of Map[String,Any]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`.

I had googled about the warning, and almost all answers are told that scala running time will erase the type when do pattern match, and it seems to be reasonable to answer the question, But when I use the following code:

```
val e = Map("1" -> "2", "3" -> 4)
e match {
    case map: Map[String, Any] => println(map)
    case _ => println("should not be here")
}
```

there is not warning about type erase, so what's the difference between this two kinds of pattern matching, and please explain when the type erase will happen, thanks!

Comment: Why introducing the `Any` issue at first?

Comment: @cchantep I introduce the `Any` issue at first cause I feel very confused about the type erase of pattern matching, the second code block makes me feel a little doubtful for the running time type erase.

Comment: Better to fix the first issue rather than trying to workaround such consequence of lossing the type safety

Answer (score 5):

The problem with matching `: Map[String, Any]` is that it's only actually possible to check you got a `Map` at runtime. So e.g.

```
val d: Any = Map(0 -> 0)
d match {
    case map: Map[String, Any] => println(map)
    case _ => println("should not be here")
}
```

The match will succeed and the map will be printed. In the second case the static type of `e` is already `Map[String, Any]`. So the compiler "knows" that you can't get any other type of `Map` and there's no issue to warn about.

But type erasure still happens. And it means that you actually *can* get something other then a `Map[String, Any]` in `e`, but only by lying to the compiler in some way or ignoring other warnings. In this case the match still succeeds. E.g.

```
val e = Map(0 -> 0).asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
e match {
    case map: Map[String, Any] => println(map)
    case _ => println("should not be here")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in [Programming in Scala](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html)

First time you get a warning since d is forced to a type of Any. Second time compiler infers type of e as Map[String, Int] which is what in the first case expression of pattern match. Compiler knows the type at compile time so nothing to warn about.